# Expand closest div with class

Tags: jquery

I have structure:

```
<div class="main-class">
 <p class="cp_view_card_details"> Click </p>
</div>
<div class="cp_expanded_view">
   <!-- Information -->
</div>
```

And it's repeat 3 times. 
In Css:

```
.cp_expanded_view {
  display:none;
}
```

So I want to expand closest element with `cp_expanded_view` class. 
My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".cp_view_card_details").click(function() {

    $(this).next('.cp_expanded_view').slideToggle('2000',
      function() {

      });

  });
});
```

jQuery code doesn't work and doesn't show any error. 
How can I make nearest `cp_expanded_view` to shown up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parent` to find next desire class. `cp_expanded_view` class is next to `main-class` class.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".cp_view_card_details").click(function() {
$(this).parent().next('.cp_expanded_view').slideToggle('2000', function() {

 });

  });
});
```

```css
.cp_expanded_view {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-class">
  <p class="cp_view_card_details"> Click </p>
</div>
<div class="cp_expanded_view">
  Show Hidden info
  <!-- Information -->
</div>
```